# Icons not showing in nested react-navigation bar

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-navigation

Following the example of [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/#a-native-stack-navigator-for-each-tab) docs page from `React Navigation`, I created a nested bottom navigation system for my React Native app (simplified version of my code can be seen and tested [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@bfrangi/test-problem)). However, I have noticed that the icons for the pages shown in the navigation bar are the typical question mark symbols (on iOS) that show when the image is not recognized:
[image: this image]

However, if I use a simple navigation bar, with no nesting, the icons are shown no problem. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: what do you want to fix ??

Comment: I want to be able to use *nested navigation* with *icons*. Right now I either have the nested navigation or the icons: both don't work at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was: I was adding the icon into the deepest (second) layer of the navigation bar. When using nested navigation bars, the icons must be placed in the highest level navigation layer. [Here](https://snack.expo.dev/@bfrangi/test-solution) is a working version of the previous example, with the appropriate correction.